# System.InvalidOperationException in WCF and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have a solution (XYZ) with 4 projects (XYZ.Domain, XYZ.Data, XYZ.Service and XYZ.Client). I need to run the WCF web service. This is my code:

```
namespace XYZ.Domain
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    // Updated properties
    [DataContract]
    public class X : BaseClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        public int Xx { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string Xy { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool Xz { get; set; }

        // Relationship with Y 1:1
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Y y { get; set; }
    }

    // Updated properties
    [DataContract]
    public class Y : BaseClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Yx {get; set;}

        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string Yy {get; set;}

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Yz {get; set;}

        // foreign key from Z
        [DataMember]
        public int Zx {get; set;}

        // Relationship with X 1:1
        [DataMember]
        public virtual X x {get; set;}

        // Relationship with Z *:1
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Z z { get; set; }
    }

    // Updated properties
    [DataContract]
    public class Z : BaseClass
    {
        public Z()
        {
            this.y = new HashSet<Y>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        public int Zx {get; set;}

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Zy {get; set;}

        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public float Zz {get; set;}

        // Relationship with Y 1:*
        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Y> y { get; set; }
    }

    // Added as a base class for my IServiceXYZ 
    [KnownType(typeof(X))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Y))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Z))]
    [DataContract]
    public class BaseClass
    {
        // empty
    }
}
```

This is the Data layer:

```
namespace XYZ.Data
{   
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using XYZ.Domain;

    public class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Entities()
            : base("name=Database")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Entities>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Entities>());
        }

        // Set of XYZ.Domain entity class
        public DbSet<X> X { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Y> Y { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Z> Z { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.y)
                .WithRequired(e => e.x);

            modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
                .Property(e => e.Xy)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
                .Property(e => e.Xz);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Y>()
                .Property(e => e.Yy)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Y>()
                .Property(e => e.Yz);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Z>()
                .HasMany(e => e.y)
                .WithRequired(e => e.z)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.Zx)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Z>()
                .Property(e => e.Zy);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Z>()
                .Property(e => e.Zz);
        }
    }

    // Interface for Generic Repository where T : XYZ.Domain Entities
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        void Insert(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
    }

    // Class generic for database persistence
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            using (var _context = new Entities())
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            using (var _context = new Entities())
            {               
                try
                {
                    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            using (var _context = new Entities())
            {                
                try
                {
                    _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This is the Service layer:

```
namespace XYZ.Service
{
    using XYZ.Domain;
    using XYZ.Data;

    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IServiceXYZ" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceXYZ
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Insert(BaseClass entity);

        [OperationContract]
        void Update(BaseClass entity);

        [OperationContract]
        void Delete(BaseClass entity);
    }

    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class ServiceXYZ : IServiceXYZ
    {
        private IGenericRepository<BaseClass> dao;

        public ServiceXYZ()
        {
            dao = new GenericRepository<BaseClass>();
        }

        public void Insert(BaseClass entity)
        {
            dao.Insert(entity);
        }

        public void Update(BaseClass entity)
        {
            dao.Update(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(BaseClass entity)
        {
            dao.Delete(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the client test:

```
namespace XYZ.Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    // Service reference
    using XYZ.Test.ServiceXYZ;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ServiceXYZOf_BaseClassClient client = new ServiceXYZOf_BaseClassClient();

                X x = new X
                {
                    Xx = 1,
                    Xy = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑ",
                    Xz = false
                };

                client.Insert(x);
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (SystemException ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But this is the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in XYZ.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The entity type BaseClass is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: I've done what are attempting, trust me implement it the way I am suggesting to you below.  Generics is not a viable option for WCF Soap Services.

Comment: best practice is to NOT share your entities all the way but only retain them right at the data layer but create your POCO representations of them and pass the POCO's around. abstract away from the tight coupling you are doing. It will save you a lot of headaches and issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a service contract based on Generics is not a good idea, you'd have to update your web.config with all the possible datatypes for your service contract.

If you insist on this type of configuration then you need to have the WCF Service use a serializer that will embed CLR data type information in the payload.  The NetdataContractSerializer will do that, you should also have common assembly(s) that both the client and server share to hold these data types.

If you are trying to do "pure" WCF then what you are doing is not going to jive with all the gotcha's that you'll have to contend with.

You can create a service that sends any object that is a subclass of some base class, for example if your class X, Y and Z all extended a base class ( let's call it `BaseClass`) then your service contract could be based off of that.

So you'd end up with a service like this:

```
public class ServiceXYZ : IServiceXYZ
{
    // XYZ.Data persistence object



    public void Insert(BaseClass entity)
    {
        //get EF Context 
        var Context = new Entities();  // <-- some method to get your EF context
        Context.Entry(entity).State = Added;  //<- this will attach and add         
    }
```

Now you need to add all `KnownTypes` of `BaseClass`, WCF needs to know what the possible .NET types could be for `BaseClass`

```
[KnownType(typeof(X)]
[KnownType(typeof(Y)]
[KnownType(typeof(Z)]
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

And you'd need to change your data contract to extend the `BaseClass`

```
[DataContract]   
public class X : BaseClass  { ...}

[DataContract]   
public class Y : BaseClass  { ...}

[DataContract]   
public class Z : BaseClass  { ...}
```

**UPDATE**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceXYZ   // NO GENERICS!! YOU BASE CLASS
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Insert(BaseClass entity);

    [OperationContract]
    void Update(BaseClass entity);

    [OperationContract]
    void Delete(BaseClass entity);
}
```

As I have already explained above you can simply attach an entity by using the Context and setting an entities state.  Look at the implementation of the Service class I did...

Comment: they should contain all their properties.

Comment: no, i don't think you are understanding how this works.  Are you doing code first of DB First?  I have implemented this and it works perfectly.

Comment: your methods can accept arguments of type `BaseClass` but are instances of X,Y or Z....  just try it...  pass a instance of X over the wire and then on server set it's state to Added

Comment: and it is still wrong, the WCF interface and implementation must NOT HAVE generics, get rid of them!!!

Comment: are you still using generics in the service or the data contract?  What I saw of your code, you weren't following what I have advised.

Comment: Well your "Updated" question has this:  `public class ServiceXYZ : IServiceXYZ<BaseClass>` and that is not what I suggested.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mis understood your last comment...  i don't have time to peruse your code... update your question with your service info, data contracts etc... what's up there is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry @T McKeown, you're right. I changed this line:

_context.Set<T>().Add(entity);

for this other:

 _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;

And it works!... My only problem is when I try to get all information from one specific table. But it's ok, thank you so much men!.